# ASP.NET JSON Binding data with RadiobuttonList

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I'm trying to bind JSON data into the RadioButtonList on client side. I know how to do the in code behind, it works fine. Someone please provide more details, How do I bind the JSON data RadioButtionList in VB.NET.

```
rblregions.DataTextField = "Value"
rblregions.DataValueField = "Key"
rblregions.DataSource = items
```

The data looks like: `[regions:{regionID:US,regionName:USA}]`

main.aspx

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblregions" runat="server">

$.getJSON("Map/loadMySites.aspx?" + query,
    function (data) {
        if (data.regionid && data.region) {
            //I want to bind the data here with RadioButtonList
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: you want to to do it on client side or server side ? if client side how does the HTML looks like ?

Comment: I want to bind it on client side using VB.NET. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

VB.NET is server side. **You can not do it client side with VB.NET**. You should do it with javascript.

The ASP.NET tag for radio button list usually generates an HTML table. Let's assume it is something like this

```
<table id="rblregions"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Assuming you are getting a `JSON` like this from your server page,

```
{
    "regions": [
        { "regionID": "US", "regionName": "USA" },
        { "regionID": "UK", "regionName": "United Kingdom" }
    ]
}
```

You can do like this

```
$.getJSON("Map/loadMySites.aspx?" + query,function(data){
    var rows="";
    $.each(data.regions,function(index,item){
        rows+="<tr><td>"+item.regionName+"</td></tr>";
    });    
    $("#rblregions> tbody:last").append(rows);    
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/LM6fF/10/

If your radio button list is inside another asp.net container element(ex panel), The ID of the element will be not like `rblregions`. so i recommend you to use class name instead of ID as the jQuery selector.

[jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a good tool to validate your JSON.

Comment: +1 because you took the time to explain the problem and even put together a working sample of a solution, and got no kind of acknowledgement from the OP.